# Import SketchUp ".skp" files

Tags: import, file-format, compatibility

I am new with Blender. I changed to it because now I am using Ubuntu. Previously on *Windows* I used to work with SketchUp, and I still have many projects, that I would like to import *.skp into Blender to continue modeling and or rendering.

**Is there any way how I could import SketchUp's `.skp` file into Blender?**

Comment: This might be interesting https://sites.google.com/site/alexvaqp/sketchupblender

Comment: @iKlsR thanks a lot. It might help me, but is there any way that I could do that without coming back to SketchUp?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an importer for this. I poked around a bit and it seems most people export to `.dae` or `.obj` and then import into Blender. Your best option I think is to get on a windows machine and export them to either of these formats.

Comment: it should be noted that it is possible to run sketchup under [wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21290). some [instructions.](http://ubuntuforums.orgshowthread.php?t=1860786) Possibly the easiest way to set this up would be to use [Play On Linux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But on my PC SketchUp crashes at startup...

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis if you have a copy of windows you could try using a virtual machine. You could even grab a free preview of windows 8 or something like that.

Comment: I'll try to do that on my friends PC (with Windows) to avoid harassing for installing heavy ppa, witch _would_ be temporal... Thank you so much.

Comment: There is an importer that only works for Windows/Mac.
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360406-Sketchup-%28SKP%29-importer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a direct importer for `.skp` files into Blender. Given your situation of being on linux at the moment, your best option is to get access to a windows machine and export to either `.obj` or `.dae` and import into Blender. If you are using the free version of sketchup, you might have to go through a few more steps.

There is an article of an extension on how to do this [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/alexvaqp/sketchupblender)

To run Sketchup on Linux you can use wine for instructions With a web search [this](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/sketchup-ubuntu-xerus.html) was found.

Or perhaps an extension on Sketchup might be http://sketchup2blender.com/blendup-get-started

Comment: You don't to use a Windows machine, just the 8 hour trial version of SketchUp in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/) in Ubuntu.... You can download the exe's [here](http://www.sketchup.com/download/all)...

Comment: @wilf Yes, that and using a virtual machine were also suggested in the comments on the question.

Comment: 17000 views, this needs a better answer. Will update it soon.

Comment: if video helps I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFDQq2zVhuM

Answer (score 10):

`.skp` is a closed file format, this means the specifications for the file are only available to

- developers with access to the [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) (Software Development Kit) and therefore have accepted the licensing terms for the SDK (which is incompatible with Blender's license).
- developers who are willing to stick time into reverse engineering it.

It is unlikely that blender will get a way to import `.skp` files directly because there are several alternative ways to get models from SketchUp into Blender. Exporting as Collada `.dae` format from SketchUp works very well.

Answer (score 5):

## Keeping all the layers

The best procedure is that shown by Sixthlaw [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtNJmbg4WK0). Because if you export it directly as `.dae` you loose all the informations regarding the layers and you will have many surprises. So is better to follow this procedure:

1. Export your model to `.dxf` from SketchUp
2. Download and install [Autdodesk-FBX-Converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives) to
3. convert the `.dfx` to `.fbx`
4. convert the `.fbx` to `.obj`

Now you can import it in Blender.

1. go to `import` ->`Wavefront(.obj)`
2. set `Forward:` to `Y Forward`
3. import the model

Comment: Softpedia? Is there an official source to get that app?

Comment: Thanks. I don't really need this app myself, I just feel uncomfortable with download hubs and don't want people to get [infected with adware](https://www.howtogeek.com/189176/why-we-hate-recommending-software-downloads-to-our-readers/), etc. (:

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but if you came accross this like me you can try convert them to .kmz then change the file extension to .zip and extract the files and see the .dae and textures.

Comment: Blender 2.83.5 crashes when I try this method.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I came across this as an issue as well. The AutoCAD converter I had tried using didn't work out too well. But I was able to, after installing the latest version of Sketchup 8, export directly from Sketchup in the .obj format and import directly into Blender. Of course you have to remember to turn on the plugin in the User Preferences menu.

The exporting options, like the other answers have stated, don't tend to work out too well. The file loses translation in between programs. Merging layers and codes or omitting them altogether. I think the first time I tried using the .dae it turned a bracket into this weird spikey ball vector. So I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an import option available, called *sketchup_importer_0.18_win64*. I used it to import `.skp` files directly into Blender.
However, the guy who wrote the software, has to upgrade it to the latest version of Blender, and (even worse) he only wrote it for Windows, not Linux.
Now, others stated running blender in Wine, but I would rather use the importer from him.
My options at the moment are building in SketchUp, open an older version of Blender, import and save, then open the latest Blender. All in Windows.

Comment: That could work, although using Windows may not be an option. I'd be surprised if it worked _only_ on Windows, though maybe it uses some Windows-specific API or something.

Comment: @seaturtle It's a partly binary plugin, having a .dll file. However, the source code is available. https://github.com/martijnberger/pyslapi/releases

Comment: Ah, that's good! Although nobody can actually use that to help unless they get permission from the person who wrote it, as they don't seem to have included a license file.

Answer (score -1):

A new addon release for sketchup to blender users

[Addon](https://github.com/martijnberger/pyslapi/releases/tag/0.15)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YZdrBp2dJE)

Comment: New? There have been no commits for 2 years.  Need blender 2.77 with python 3.4 or 3.5.  Is not available for linux.  Is mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @batFINGER I think the question is not for Linux its about importing sketchup model into Blender

Comment: _I am using Ubuntu_ (in the question)