# Importing large file from Sketchup

Tags: import

How do I import a large SketchUp file to blender? The 3ds file/collide is 117.3 MB

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/import-sketchup-skp-files?rq=1

Comment: @gandalf3 not quite the case, if a file is heavy/huge in terms of size its not importing to blender, Im looking for a way to work around it.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an error message from something? If so, could you include the error in your question?

Comment: @gandalf3 no error message so far. Its taking more than two hours to import into blender, so I was looking for another alternative of importing the file or how to make the file size smaller to import into blender.

Comment: The more information we have, the more likely we'll be able to answer your question. For instance, do you get any output in the [system console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6173/599)?